# Validar la existencia del ID de un producto desde el Backend (utilizando socket.io) para que aparezca una Alert en el front

Tags: javascript, html, socket.io

Voy a dejar el codigo en el cual estoy trabajando, Los archivos pertenecientes al Back son "productManager.js -> aqui se encuentran los metodos", "app.js -> Lo que envio y recibo de socket.io" y "index.js -> Las acciones en el Front".
Como back estoy utilizando persistencia de datos con FileSystem (solo por ahora)

Quiero realizar una validación en el metodo "deleteProduct()" que se encuentra en productManager.
Dicha validacion tiene que comprobar que el ID ingresado desde el front este en la db y en caso de no existir enviar una Alerta.

"productManager.js"

```
import fs from 'fs';


export default class ProductManager {
    constructor(){
        this.path = './src/files/products.json';
    }

    validateField(){
        throw('Error - Campo sin parametro');    
    }

    getProducts = async () =>{
       
        if(!fs.existsSync(this.path)){
            return [];
        }
        
        const products = await fs.promises.readFile(this.path, 'utf-8');
        
        const productsJSON = JSON.parse(products);
                
        return productsJSON;
    }

    getProductById = async (id) =>{

        const products = await this.getProducts();
                
        const product = products.filter( e => e.id === parseInt(id))

        return product;
    }

    addProduct = async (product=this.validateField()) =>{
     
        let products = await this.getProducts();
        
        if(products.length === 0 ){
            product.id = 1;
            product.status = true;
        } else {
            product.id = products[products.length -1 ].id + 1;
        }

        let numCode = products.find((e) => e.code === product.code);

        if(numCode){
            return 'El codigo de producto no puede estar presente en 2 productos';
        }

        products.push(product);

        try {

            await fs.promises.writeFile(this.path, JSON.stringify(products, null, '\t'))
            return 'Producto agregado'

        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }

    }

    deleteProduct = async (id) =>{

        const products = await this.getProducts();
        
        let indexProduct = products.findIndex((e)=>{
            return e.id === parseInt(id);
        })

        if(indexProduct === -1){
            return {
                existe: false
            }
        }

        products.splice(indexProduct, 1);
    

        try {
            
            await fs.promises.writeFile(this.path, JSON.stringify(products, null, '\t'))
            return {
                del_mensaje: `El producto eliminado es el ID: ${id}`
            }


        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }

    }
}
```

"app.js"

```
import express from 'express';
import { Server } from 'socket.io';
import handlebars from "express-handlebars";
import __dirname from './utils.js';
import productsRouter from './routes/products.router.js';
import cartsRouter from './routes/carts.router.js';
import viewsRouter from './routes/views.router.js';
import ProductManager from './managers/productManager.js';

const PORT = '8080';
const app = express();
const server = app.listen(PORT, ()=>{
    console.log(`Servidor UP! en Puerto: ${PORT}`);
});

const manager = new ProductManager();
const socketServer = new Server(server);

app.engine('handlebars', handlebars.engine());
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine','handlebars');

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));



app.use('/api/products', productsRouter);
app.use('/api/carts', cartsRouter);
app.use('/', viewsRouter);



socketServer.on('connection', async socket=>{
    console.log("Conectado")
    
    const products = await manager.getProducts();
    socket.emit('log', products);
    
    socket.on('add_product', async data =>{
        await manager.addProduct(data);
        const products = await manager.getProducts();
        socketServer.emit('log', products);
    })

    socket.on('del_product', async data =>{
       
        await manager.deleteProduct(data.id);
        const products = await manager.getProducts();
        socketServer.emit('log', products);
        
    })

})
```

"index.js" -> front!

```
const socket = io();
const nodo = document.querySelector('#nodo')
const title = document.querySelector('#title')
const price = document.querySelector('#price')
const stock = document.querySelector('#stock')
const thumbnail = document.querySelector('#thumbnail')
const description = document.querySelector('#description')
const category = document.querySelector('#category')
const code = document.querySelector('#code')
const agregar = document.querySelector('#agregar')
const borrar = document.querySelector('#borrar')
const idProd = document.querySelector('#id')
const hijo = document.querySelector('#hijo')
const form = document.querySelector('#primeForm')

socket.on('log', products => {
    

    let hijo = '';

    products.forEach(e => {
        hijo += `
            <ul id="${e.id}" class="list-group mb-5"> 
                <li class="list-group-item">ID: ${e.id}</li>
                <li class="list-group-item"><h3>${e.title}</h3></li>
                <li class="list-group-item">Codigo: ${e.code}</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">Precio: $ ${e.price}</li> 
                <li class="list-group-item">Descripcion: ${e.description}</li> 
            </ul>
        `;
        nodo.innerHTML = hijo;
    });
});



agregar.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    socket.emit('add_product', {
        title: title.value,
        price: price.value,
        stock: stock.value,
        thumbnail: thumbnail.value,
        description: category.value,
        code: code.value
    });
});




borrar.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    if(idProd.value===null || !idProd.value){
        alert('Ingresar Nro ID')
    }else {
    socket.emit('del_product', {
        id: idProd.value
    })
}
})
```

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Has publicado una buena cantidad de código y aún así luce incompleto, creo que falta _reducir_ (eliminar) lo que no es esencial para entender el problema que estás teniendo. Un [mcve] sería lo ideal para tu pregunta. Para más información, date una vuelta por [ask].